# can I use ssh to send build command for android building?

Tags: ssh, tmux, openssh

I'm new in Linux, but learning bits by bits.. So please give explanation too, instead of only the answer, to help me understand about why and how.

Currently I want to build an android rom with Xubuntu OS. I already setup openSSH to connect remotely. my remote pc is win10, using putty for ssh.

my question are:
can I use ssh to build android rom? Can I use "brunch" command, and disconnect ssh connection? 
-- If can, then how can I know if the process is finished or not?
-- if can't, then any other method to do that remotely? beside using vnc? or is there any way to remote only the running terminal app on my server? so that what's on remote screen = server's terminal screen. something like that

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want look into `GNU screen` or `tmux`.  they both have  the attach feature.
typical workflow looks like this:

1. Connect with SSH
2. Start a screen/tmux session.
3. Do your work.
4. Disconnect.
5. Next time you login, attach the last session and continue working.

Comment: will the session be visible on screen on server's side? which one u suggest? gnu screen or tmux?

Comment: @dokie80 you can also attach the session from a Terminal Window on server. I suggest tmux.

Comment: Looks good. Going to read some and try. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Tmux is just what i ve been looking for. Again, Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I was going to... but cant find any button to close this question... :D